# Width of element with fixed position Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got an element with `width=auto`. When when I add `position: fixed` to that element, it visually changes its width. How can I keep the aspect of the element after  adding `position: fixed`? I want a responsive and centered element with position 'fixed'.

This is an example of the problem (class `first` and `first_top`) : http://jsfiddle.net/nWHSH/

Comment: Your problem may be on the way you are using bootstrap. If you pay attention to the way you are using your table cells and its CSS you ca see there is a lot of interference there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was in your `first_top`CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/nWHSH/6/

This should solve your problem, just change your CSS to:

```
.first_top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The problem was about the fixed positioning. **Fixed and absolute positioned elements are detached from the actual document flow**, so they tend to not react with other elements naturally, they interact with the document it self.

So in order to force the order within the flow, you have to guide that sam element and make him follow a flow that is not the main one, but is similar, giving the user the idea that it is really being manipulated by the interaction with the other objects in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nWHSH/2/)

centring element after position fixed

```
var elem = $('.first');
    var firstTop = elem.offset().top, firstH = elem.height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if( $(window).scrollTop() > firstTop ) {
        elem.removeClass('first_top').addClass('first_top');
        $('.sticker').css({display: 'block', height: firstH});
          $(".first_top").css("left", ($(window).width()- $(".first_top").width())/2);
      } else {
        $('.first').removeClass('first_top');
        $('.sticker').css({display: 'none', height: '0'});
      }
    });
```

Comment: But the width of the element is still changing. I want to keep it always the same.